# What is the CSS Selector path to find text()

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I am using

```
WebElement AdministratorMessage=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Your new administrator(s) have been created and invitation email(s) sent')"));

<div class="saveMsg nd___highlighted" ng-show="showBanner==true" style="display: none; outline: rgb(204, 0, 0) dashed 2px;">
<i class="fa fa-check" style="outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;"></i>
                Your new administrator(s) have been created and invitation email(s) sent
                <i class="fa fa-close msgClose" ng-click="hideSuccessMsg()"></i>
            </div>
```

Error Message:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An
>   invalid or illegal selector was specified   (Session info:
>   chrome=48.0.2564.116)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078
>   (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.3
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html Build
>   info: version: '2.48.2', revision:
>   '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09
>   13:08:06' System info: host: 'INDIA-DEV36', ip: '192.168.186.56',
>   os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_60' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\HARSH~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8680_6077},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   hasTouchScreen=false, version=48.0.2564.116, platform=WIN8_1,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   cfd3e5b7a892aca75855ba4299c03bac
>   *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=div:contains('Your new administrator(s) have been created and invitation email(s) sent')}    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:492)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>     at
>   com.atlassian.webdriver.DefaultAtlassianWebDriver.findElement(DefaultAtlassianWebDriver.java:232)
>     at
>   com.client.app.pages.AdministratorHome.isAdministratorEmailMessageDisplayed(AdministratorHome.java:283)
>     at
>   com.client.app.administrator.CreateAdministratorCondecoSenseStepDefs.verify_SucessMessageDisplayed(CreateAdministratorCondecoSenseStepDefs.java:129)
>     at ✽.Then New Administrator created successfully
>   US171AutoEmail@condecosoftware.com,Your new administrator(s) have been
>   created and invitation email(s)
>   sent(src/test/resources/com/client/app/sense_administrator/CreateAdministratorCondeco.feature:22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't search for text in the find using CSS selectors. You will have to find the element(s) and search for the desired text.

```
WebElement administratorMessage = null;
String searchText = "Your new administrator(s) have been created and invitation email(s) sent";
List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.saveMsg.nd___highlighted"));
for (WebElement div : divs)
{
    if (div.getText().contains(searchText))
    {
        administratorMessage = div;
        break;
    }
}

if (administratorMessage != null)
{
    // searchText found
}
else
{
    // searchText NOT found
    System.out.println("No element was found containing the message, \"" + searchText + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using this selector:

```
By.cssSelector("div:contains('Your new administrator(s) have been created and invitation email(s) sent')")
```

`css selector` does not support `contains`. Therefore you are getting an error saying the `selector` is invalid.

If you want to use `contains` you should make use of `xpath`.

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Your new administrator(s) have been created and invitation email(s) sent')])
```

Comment: I have to use Css selector because using xpath it is not working this message display on the screen for 5 sec and Xpath not able to find it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try to find it using xpath, try this...

```
By.xpath("//span[text()='Text']")
```